# Django Celery Results Table Missing periodictaskname and taskname Fields

Tags: celery, django-celery, periodic-task, django-celery-beat, django-celery-results

I have set up Django with Celery, using django_celery_results and django_celery_beat to schedule tasks and store the results. The tasks are running successfully, but I've encountered an issue with the django_celery_results table.

The django_celery_results table in my database only contains UUID, task state, and completed time. However, I expected to see additional fields such as periodictaskname and taskname. The absence of these fields is causing difficulties in tracking and managing scheduled tasks.

```
`#celery.py`
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
```

I have reviewed the documentation for django_celery_results and django_celery_beat but couldn't find a clear solution. I also checked my Celery configuration, and everything seems to be in order.

I expect the django_celery_results table to include fields such as periodictaskname and taskname in addition to UUID, task state, and completed time.

Answer (score 0):

`django_celery_results` alredy includes these fields: Task ID, Periodic Task Name, Task Name, Completed DateTime, Task State, Worker.

Please be sure `django_celery_results` is added to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "celery",
    "django_celery_beat",
    "django_celery_results",
    ...
]
```

Please do not forget database migration after adding apps. Then, you should return result in dict type, after celery tasks done like this sample:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def analyze_all_posts(self, *args, **kwarg):
    posts = Post.objects.all()  # Example
    try:
        return {"status": True, "message": f"{len(posts)} post(s) analyzed"}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"status": False, "message": str(e)}
```

Comment: This return the dictionary of results which is getting stored in <Result Data> inside celery results not in periodic task name and task name. Is there something I am missing to configure?

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py we need to have `CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED =True` for the taskname to show up in the celery results table. This does show the task name and worker name but the periodic taskname is not getting populated.